# For old version of Tizen - How to uninstall an app in Tizen emulator?

Tags: tizen, tizen-emulator

**This question is for one of the earliest versions of Tizen and does not apply to current versions**

I'm just getting started with Tizen. I managed to install a HelloWorld app on the emulator, but I can't find a way to uninstall it. What am I missing?

Please see the following screen shot of the Settings menu on the emulator. The pre-loaded apps are listed under Application, but the app I installed is not there.

[image: Settings on Tizen emulator]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by using `sdb` command.

```
$ sdb -e uninstall <AppId>
```

You can find your app's AppId in manifest.xml. AppId consists of random 10 characters (alphabets and digits).

BTW, Tizen 2.1 (yet to be publicly released) has uninstall function in the Settings app.

Comment: This looks like it would be the right way to do it, but sdb returns an error when I run that command with my app's ID. "processing request 2 failed". I only have 1 emulator running and I checked that it is detected by running "sdb devices". I also tried running "sdb start-server" and then retried uninstalling, but that didn't work either. Maybe that command only works for apps installed with "sdb install"? I installed mine with the Run button on the Tizen IDE.

Comment: Can you paste the result of 'sdb uninstall' command? I was able to uninstall the app I installed with the Run button. Have you tried it with a brand-new emulator? I mean create an emulator, install your app on it, then uninstall the app by the command.

Comment: Hmm ... don't know what was wrong the last time, but I tried a new emulator as you suggested and succeeded in uninstalling. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Open tizen shell by right-clicking on the emulator then select [Shell].

```
wrt-installer -ug <guid>
```

or

```
wrt-installer -un <package_name>
```

You can find guid at [Overview] page of config.xml.

Package name is the tizen application ID. You can find it at [Tizen] page of config.xml.

for example,

```
wrt-installer -ug http://yourdomain/HelloWorld
```

or

```
wrt-installer -un Spp6vzPOlp
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. I used the command "wrt-installer -un 5szoHlF51E" and it returned "wrt-installer : 5szoHlF51E uninstallation has failed - widget package does not exist". I checked in the Eclipse console that package name matches (it was installed with the command "$ pkgcmd -C -t tpk -n 5szoHlF51E"). By the way, did you mean to write manifest.xml instead of config.xml? I can't find a file named config.xml in my project, but there is no guid in manifest.xml ...

Answer (score 2):

On tizen watch emulator press right-click > Control Panel > App Manager (left menu) > Unninstaller

Answer (score 1):

It's Simple just click on the settings icon which i rounded below (fig 1). Then the user apps will show a close icon(fig 2), just click on the close button which you need :)

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: This is correct, but the uninstall feature is available from Tizen 2.0. The question was for old Tizen version.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> you can uninstall the app on the phone via Settings > All > Manage
>   applications. Select the app from the list, then click on the
>   Uninstall button. You can also update an existing app from the command
>   line with:

https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Manually_installing_apps

Comment: That's the thing, there is no "Manage applications" on the emulator I'm using. All I have in Settings are the headers Connectivity, System and Application with their respective entries, but all I have are the default emulator apps under Application and no entry for "Manage applications" anywhere. For information I am using the emulator base image "emulimg-2.0.x86" that ships with the Tizen SDK.

Comment: ah just saw your edit. it's strange. it should be there. i will search for some more information :)

Comment: what if you click on frequenctly used?

Comment: nah, clicking on "Frequently used" just hides some settings in Connectivity and System. It's basically toggling between showing all items in Settings when you click "All" and filtering them when you click "Frequently used".

Comment: ah allright. but i just can't find something about deleting. i think you just have to delete the files manually. but on a real phone that is not possible. it's not well explained @ tizen docs.

Comment: I agree with you about lack of explanation. That's why I asked here ;) Thanks for searching too.

Comment: i gave up searching. can not find something :) and it looks like this isn't a populiar question. only 8 views in 1 hour. but anyway. if my answer was a bit helpful don't forget to accept. and if you need some help i could help you out maybe.

Answer (score 0):

On top left of the Tizen menu screen there is a setting icon, just click that icon and you can view all the user installed applications which can be uninstalled. Select your application from it and your app is uninstalled.